# Where to save video on iPhone?

Tags: ios, video, save, gallery, assets

My app is recording video and creating other documents and meta data - looks like all the Apple docs and other code refer to saving it in photos album or camera roll [are these two different?] using AssetsLibrary - would this not mix up all my app's videos with the rest ?

I cannot find either Apple or any book that gives best practice to store custom media files separately in the file system and display using custom gallery - no good pointers even in Stackflow. Can some iOS guru point me to some good examples.

Note I am not asking about how to read/write video, etc. The question is how to organize a custom gallery using filesystem and a datastore and is it the right way to do it? If not, what other options? What are the pros/cons of AssetsLibrary?

Thanks.

Comment: do you not want your videos to be usable by other apps, or visible to the user from *outside* of your app?  you want them completely separate?

Comment: was planning to keep entirely separate with option to export to camera roll - what other options might the user want?

Comment: sure explains why democracy fails...

Comment: Bob, unfortunately, Stack Overflow doesn't have democracy.  It has an inbred oligarchy, where a small group of *high-reputation* jerks waste their time shutting down people's attempts to do their work, out of some OCD run-wild, or perhaps a misguided belief that less content makes for a better internet site (a belief that has been conclusively debunked many times).

Comment: was asking a simple valid design question for which i could not find a proper answer anywhere - and as many as five people found the time to flag it as not-constructive - why so? - do any of you know the answer to the question? - why not you instead spend the time to find the answer and help if you can - if not, just go about your way - it is easy to criticize or "flag" - do you get points for that also - what are you going to do with all the points after you die? - just stop and think instead of using your keyboard or mouse... - thanks to the person who answered.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, SO does *reward* people for closing questions with badges and the like.  It's insane.  I like a lot of things about the site, but this aspect is ridiculous.

Comment: thanks for your support Nate - good to know there are others who agree - democracy may survive after all :) anyway, just wanted to post that i found a good answer/explanation to my question with this guide, which i could not locate before - but only after searching around from the pointers given by ohr below - perhaps this guide can  help someone else also:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store them in your documents directory. This is only accesible to your application. You can get a reference to that folder with this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Apple recommends using `NSFileManager` to create, move, and delete files.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
```

> The NSFileManager class enables you to perform many generic file-system operations and insulates an app from the underlying file system.

[NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSFileManager) documentation.

[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains)

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply [i was away last week] - good to know that what you've suggested is a correct option [had seen it used in other code].

Comment: now, though what i was really really looking for is a more high level set of classes or framework to display and manage a custom gallery with ability to move, delete, search/sort files with dragndrop, say similar to Finder on Mac [beats me why Apple doesn't provide one as i can imagine most apps needing something like that]